# Return file if exists, otherwise return false

Tags: swift, swift3, extension-methods

I'm trying to make a String extension that searches for a file in my app's directory and either returns that file or returns false if it does not exist. Here's what I have:

```
extension String {
    func doesFileWithNameExist() -> Bool {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(self+".png")?.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Right now my function just returns a Bool, but I'm wondering if there's a way to just return the file if it exists, otherwise return false. Is there a way to return different value types from a function?

Comment: Return `nil` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean to make my function return a `UIImage?`?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly recommended to use the URL related API. This returns an optional `UIImage`:

```
extension String {
    func doesFileWithNameExist() -> UIImage? { // maybe better pngImageInDocumentsFolder()
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            let url = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let fullURL = url.appendingPathComponent(self).appendingPathExtension("png")
            _ = try fullURL.checkResourceIsReachable()
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fullURL)
            return UIImage(data: data)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

or using Leo's great reduction (slightly still reduced):

```
var image: UIImage? { 
    guard let url = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(self).appendingPathExtension("‌​png"), 
          let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(data: data) 
}
```

Comment: I get the warning  `Result of call to 'checkResourceIsReachable()' is unused` on the line `try fullURL.checkResourceIsReachable()`, is this ok?

Comment: That's a very confusing function name for what it does and returns.

Comment: `var image: UIImage? {
        if let url = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(self).appendingPathExtension("png"),
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }`

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed, I added a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an **optional** value here, which in Swift is "a thing or nil" – very close to "that file or false." For example, here's a quick tweak to your extension function that returns the path if a file exists there, or nil otherwise:

```
extension String {
    func doesFileWithNameExist() -> String? {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(self+".png")?.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
            return filePath
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

A quick editorial comment, though: this kind of behavior doesn't seem especially well-suited to a String extension. I'd consider writing an extension on FileManager instead, passing in a string for the file's name. Given the hardcoding of the "png" extension, maybe something with the following signature?

```
extension FileManager {
    func pathToExistingPNGFile(named name: String) -> String? {
        // …
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me, but wouldn't it be easier to just return an optional UIImage?

Comment: Sure, depending on what you want to do. With respect, the original question was a little ambiguous: "returns that file," plus the snippet, could mean "return the path," "return the data contents of the file," "return an NSFileWrapper," "return the file in a type-specific class (like UIImage)," etc. Looks like @vadian's answer covered those grounds, though.